# Motorola MG7700 on XFINITY, mysterious user IDs and passwords

Tags: router, internet-security

I did a "backup" via the user interface on my Motorla MG7700 modem/router connected to Xfinity.  In the dump, I found all IDs and passwords are unencrypted.  Motorola acknowledges that much.

What they do not discuss is that there are two other valid user ID/password pairs which I did not put there, and which I cannot change via the user interface.  Did Motorola or Xfintity put them there?  How can I disable them or change their passwords?

Comment: They're probably super-user IDs and passwords, either factory-set or installed by Xfinity to remotely push updates and upgrades on the modem. The strange thing isn't that they exist, but that you can actually see them. Have you read this? https://techwarior.com/xfinity-router-login/

Comment: It is not an xfinity router.  It is my own Motorola MG7700 purchased from Newegg.

Comment: Xfinity is your ISP, right? So as Moab answered, those are probably usernames and password linked to the free WiFi hotspot à la FON on your router.

Comment: Found proof that the extra IDs, including the unchangeable one, are from the factory.  That means remode admin is a security issue.  If you allow a remote admin s/he can do a settings backup.  All user ID and passwords, as well as wifi network names and passwords are captured unencrypted.  After that, changing the user ID and password are no use, because there is one admin ID/password pair which is unalterable.

Comment: As I said in a previous comment, the question is not why are those IDs and password there, because mostly all OEM leave "backdoors" (that's not what it is, technically, but let's call it that for now) in their routers, if only for maintenance purposes. The question is, how come they were left apparent? All it did was to make you nervous, for no reason, I'm sure, unless your modem was hacked before it left the factory. It's not unheard of, but rather rare, you ask me. EDIT: come to think of it, it could have been installed by Newegg too, or at their request.

Comment: Motorola has admitted to me that they baked in the extra IDs.  They claim they will fix that and the lack of encryption in a future firmware release -- no timeframe given.  Meanwhile, I have found that, with remote admin turned off, there is no outside access to the router other than Comcast provisiioning.  I also checked the guest wifi channels, and they have no visibility to the router.  Yes, unencrypted passwords bother me a lot.  Through demonstration, I convinced the executives at a then-major computer manufacturer that plaintext passwords were a bad idea.  That was forty-two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

[Comcast Xfinity](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/xfinity-wifi-hotspots) shares your wireless internet connection with anyone close by (hotspot), it is secure sharing and can be Disabled. It does not use your bandwidth allocation either.

Comment: Not true if you have your own router, which I do.

Comment: It is my own router..  There is no forced hotspot.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the admin page, please?

Comment: There are quite a few pages.  It's a fairly extensive web site.  The login page is quite uninformative.  What settings or pages did you have in mind?  (There is no user admin page; I found the other ID/pw pairs by looking at Motorola's unencrypted setting save data.)